# Mamp: Error with DB Charset in line 31

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, syntax-error, mamp

I have real trouble with setting up Wordpress. I have no idea of coding and html, but I could figure out that the issue lies in Line 31.

Mamp showed me this error:

> [10-Apr-2015 21:14:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error: syntax error,
>   unexpected 'DB_CHARSET' (T_STRING) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Wordpress/wp-config.php on line 31

I googled the mistake, but nobody had trouble with line 31. I know that it has to be utf8, and it is also in the configuration file written like this, but I really can't find the mistake. Does someone has an answer?

Thank you very much for your help.

```
 /** MySQL database username */ define('DB_USER', ‘root’);
 /** MySQL database password */ define('DB_PASSWORD', ‘root’);
 /** MySQL hostname */ define('DB_HOST', 'localhost’);
 /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */      
 define('DB_CHARSET', ‘utf8’);
```

I know, it's a syntax error, but the other post about syntax errors couldn't help me. Can someone give me an answer to this specific case.

Comment: Check your hostname line... smart quote looks like there...Actually user and password also appear to be using those quotes.

Answer (score 2):

at end of 'localhost’ you have wrong quote mark

remove it and paste the same which you have at beginning of localhost

Comment: If this is the answer you might as well point out all instances of those incorrect quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much .... Jesus, you need a little bit of understanding, the difference between those quote marks. Man, thank you all of you.